# Problems restoring grub

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gpt

I have used fsarchiver to move the content of my old hard drive on a new bigger SSD. Basically, one partition with Ubuntu 12.04. 
Everything went fine. But now I can not boot. I used GPT and I also made a smaller partition FAT32 in which I am trying to install grub, with no success.

I am, honestly, confused and not sure about what to do.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having personally destroyed my boot loader time and time again, I have become rather familiar with the following HOW TO on the Ubuntu forums:

[http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099]

Refer to the chroot section, as that is where I have met my greatest success with this particular issue. If it does not work for some reason, try it again except using the "grub-efi" package when reinstalling GRUB.

If your system STILL will not boot, check to ensure that your motherboard/system supports EFI booting. If it supports only a standard BIOS (i.e. NO UEFI or EFI booting), you will need to move your system partition off of your SSD, replace the GPT table on the SSD with a MBR table, then move the partition back onto the SSD and once again try the chroot grub recover method listed in the article above.

Hope this has been helpful.

MG

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try and post here the results! fingers crossed...

Comment: No problem. Hope all goes well for you, as I understand the frustration of not being able to boot a system.

Comment: I tried everything in the link, but I have never managed to finish the entire procedure.. I get crazy errors everywhere, many of which I did not manage to solve. I guess I will try to switch to MBR table. Anything specific I have to consider while doing it? Thanks

Comment: When do you get these crazy errors, and what do they say (if there are a ton of them, just tell me a couple that appear to be "parent errors")?

Switching to MBR from GPT mostly gets complicated when you have many partitions to move, but from the sound of it you only have one or two. Booting a live cd/usb and using gparted to copy-and-paste partitions is a fairly simple way to move them around.

Comment: yes, I basically had just one, plus the one I wanted to use to boot. Anyway, I just started restoring everything, MBR mode this time. Let's see how it goes. Thanks again!!

Comment: Sound good. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Just finished! This time no problems occurred! Finally!!! Thanks again! I would have wondered much longer before switching to MBR if it wasn't for your answer! Really.. thanks!!