# Increasing size of /home directory in Ubuntu using unallocated space

Tags: gparted

I have a 1 TB hard disk with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed (dual booted).
When I open GParted, this is what it looks like for me:

[image]

I want to increase the size of my /home (/dev/sda/11) directory using the unallocated space of 234 GiB (the one before /dev/sda6). How exactly do I accomplish this? Do I need to take a backup of my 320 GiB (/dev/sda6) partition as well (in case a live CD or USB is needed)?
I tried reading the solutions given at the following link but couldn't quite understand how to go about it.

[How to Increase Home Folder Size in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657923/how-to-increase-home-folder-size-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Answer (score 2):

Recommended to always backup important data before moving partitions.

The good news is, this does not move the boot partition causing your system not to boot.  You will have to do this from a LiveCD as you need to unmount all the partitions that have a key icon on them before you can move them.

You would need to move `sda6`, `sda9`, `sda10` and `sda11` in that order to the free space in front of them.  Then you should be able to resize `sda11` to the remaining space.

The partitions are not the same from this answer, but it is very well written:

https://askubuntu.com/a/143529/231142

Comment: Will unmounting result in loss of data?
Also, where exactly do I move sda6, sda9, sda10 and sda11 after unmounting them?

Comment: @ArnavDeshpande No, unmounting will not result in loss of data.  You do need though to do this from a LiveCD and not from booting to your hard drive, or you will have loss of data.  You cannot move a partition on a drive when you are using it.  Moving those partitions have to move to the left.  When you select them from gparted on your LiveCD and choose Move, you will see the free space to the left of each one, but only after you have moved the one before.